# ConcurrentDictionnary tryAdd

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, concurrentdictionary

When you are using `ConcurrentDictionary` and trying to add new key pairs to it using `TryAdd` it checks whether value exists and then add if not. Is there any way I can add duplicate keys wit different vales? Or maybe there is alternative thread-safe dictionary which allows to do that?

Comment: Depends on usage. One way is using ConcurrentQueue of KeyValuePair. ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Comment: Dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys, but you can do something similar by having a `Dictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>>` instead of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` cannot contain duplicate keys.

I would go with a `ConcurrentBag<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` if ordering wasn't an issue or you might use a `ConcurrenyDictionary <string, List<string>>` and filter out the proper value as needed.

Comment: Of course, if you use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>` you'll have to provide your own synchronization for the lists you are storing as values.

Comment: ConcurrentBag is not a very good choice either because it targets a very specific access pattern, it's not a generic container. ConcurrentBag uses thread local storage, so the thread that adds an item can access it cheaply, others incur a significant overhead.